# Organize [pronunciation] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm thinking of making some kind of improvement of [pronunciation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronunciation) tag.

Say, we have an English Learner who is a native speaker of a certain language.
He/she has *phonetic habits* likewise the other speakers of the same language.
He typically make the same mistakes or has typical problems, for example:

- Portuguese: [Reproducing vowel sounds, as in `pan`/`pen`](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/380/how-to-correctly-pronounce-pan-and-pen-differently)
- Italian: [Reproducing /h/](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/268/is-there-a-mnemonic-that-helps-remembering-when-i-should-use-hate-and-when-a)
- Speakers of Slavic languages: reproducing vowels as in `this`/`is` or `the`/`there`
- Japanese: distinction between /r/ and /l/

...and so on.

My question is, should we make a set of specific tags like "pronunciation-italian" to help users quickly find questions they need?
Other ideas would be also helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating tags like [pronunciation-italian](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronunciation-italian) would mean to artificially create a distinction between questions. A question about pronunciation asked by a native speaker of Italian could be interesting also for native speakers of other languages. For example, as far as I know, also in Spanish the *h* is always silent, contrary to English where the *h* is pronounced in *house*, but not in *hour*.

Knowing which language users natively speak can be useful to make them understand the pronunciation of the word (e.g. the *h* in *house* is probably pronounced like Spanish people pronounce the *j* in *Alejandro*), but that information doesn't deserve its own tag, or be added to a tag used for the question.

Comment: I could be wrong about the pronunciation of _j_ in Spanish, but as far as I recall, the Spanish equivalent of _ha ha_ is _jaja_.