# Poll: Retag questions with the "grammar" tag, or not?

Tags: discussion, tags

We've discussed this issue finely in [Is This Tag Useful? Episode 1 - The Big Boss (grammar)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2699/is-this-tag-useful-episode-1-the-big-boss-grammar) and [A proposed solution to the "grammar" dilemma -- Please contribute your answers to the "what is grammar" post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/a-proposed-solution-to-the-grammar-dilemma-please-contribute-your-answers-t). However, a recent [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/76622/can-an-adverb-modify-nouns-pronouns) came up with the tag, which was initially locked. It made me realize that not much have been said in the other posts that would signify community consensus. We still dunno whether we should burninate the tag, and leave it as a placeholder on one question, or just leave the tag be.

So the only purpose of this post is to explicitly determine the community's position regarding the tag. Should we start **removing the tag from existing questions and replacing it with more accurate tags**? Or should we **leave it be**?

#### This post is a poll. Please cast your votes on the two answers below to weigh in.

Points to consider:

- I figured some people would just upvote the solution they think is good, and others would both upvote their preferred solution and downvote the other one. To avoid inconsistency, **only the upvotes on the posts will count**. After all, you can't downvote other presidents in the election. ;) So it doesn't matter if you downvote or not, but I recommend you don't, since some people here can't see the vote counts. (It's a privilege currently awarded at 750 reps)
- Please **don't use the answer or the comments part for further discussion on the matter**. All further discussion should take place in [A proposed solution to the "grammar" dilemma -- Please contribute your answers to the "what is grammar" post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/a-proposed-solution-to-the-grammar-dilemma-please-contribute-your-answers-t).
- We'll just tally the votes in a final answer (For those who can't see the vote counts) and post a separate answer.
- The votes will be counted at 2015/12/30 and hence you can only vote up to that time if you want it to count.
- **There is now a [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33316/to-grammar-or-not-to-grammar) if you want to discuss this further freely.**

Comment: I think asking users to *delete* comments is not practical or else you'll keep on 'conveying' your message and others will deleting their own comments. In such case, ask them to **move** their comments to the question and not the answer. Others may take it in a different way that they should not post comments at all! What if the question sounds ambiguous? needs clarification? What should they do? They post comments, you reply/clarify, and they remove again?

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Who on the earth will ask questions like 'What is grammar?' 'What is its scope/' and the like on this platform? I guess we have an ELU for asking questions on linguistics. And one more thing Sir, many people who have confusion regarding the question will be benefitted by various comments, and I don't think that it will affect the voting.

Comment: @Ruchir there are advanced learners here. The fact that it's not an everyday question you see doesn't make it improbable. We have learners like DamkerngT and Listenever who prefer to study the grammar of the language in order to gain an understanding of the usage. It's not a usual method, but it's certainly a method. And again, please move your comments under the question, not here.

Comment: I am afraid, I don't agree with this. There are many (in fact most of the users), who are unaware of grammar jargons like conjunction, conditional constructions, subjunctives, determiners, participles, complementations, and many more tags. I was /am one of them. To me, the tag 'grammar' is the only way.

Comment: @Ruchir please read the chat log of the chatroom. The second option isn't about banishing users from using the tag. It's all about improving searchability.

Comment: By the way, I hope there are many tags in the pipeline. Examples include: nonce word, word, words, usage, word-usage, legal, style, as, time, formal, email, let, that, which, past, present, logic and dozens more. I'd have appreciated a *drive* against them **first.**

Comment: @Maulik yeah, but first I wanted to see if I can get the big boss. :) It would surprise you probably, but I think "meaning" should go too! ("grammaticality" is also misapplied frequently, but I think we'll find out how to deal with it) I have so many plans for tags and all I need is some cooperation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The community has decided. The poll has ended and votes have been tallied:

- **12** upvotes for the solution "remove [grammar](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) from almost all questions"
- **3** upvotes for the solution "leave [grammar](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) alone"

Hence, the majority of the community has decided that a **mass-retagging** happen. Stay tuned in, this is merely the beginning.

Answer (score 10):

## Remove [grammar](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) from most questions and let it remain on one/few <sup>1</sup> question(s) only.

---

<sub>1: I have been asked to clarify what is meant by "few". We would only leave the tag on questions that are about the linguistic term "grammar" itself: What is grammar? What does it mean? What's its scope? and suchlike. I haven't checked all the ELL questions to see if my post (What is meant by grammar?) is the only one of these kind of questions, hence I didn't just go and say "let it remain on only one question".</sub>

Comment: For more info and if you have anything to add to the discussion please visit [this post](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/a-proposed-solution-to-the-grammar-dilemma-please-contribute-your-answers-t) and **don't use the comment part for further clarifications**.

Answer (score -1):

## Don't remove [grammar](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) and let it remain.

Comment: For more info and if you have anything to add to the discussion please visit [this post](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/a-proposed-solution-to-the-grammar-dilemma-please-contribute-your-answers-t) and **don't use the comment part for further clarifications**.