# The Retagging Event -- Episode 2 (The Doom of "grammar")

Tags: discussion, chat, retagging

> **The next TRE will be held on 2016/01/02 on Saturday, recurring every 3 days.**

Since the [community agreed with](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2811/poll-retag-questions-with-the-grammar-tag-or-not/2825#2825) the proposed retagging of [grammar](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar), we're starting a chatroom event for retagging!

**The Retagging Event will be held every three days in [the chatroom dedicated solely for this purpose](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33637/my-love-hate-relationship-with-grammar) on 16:00 UTC. You can register for the event [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/33637/my-love-hate-relationship-with-grammar?tab=schedule).**

During the event, I'd appreciate it if the users that used the active tab use [the newest questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) tab instead.

Comment: For the curious, [this](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/386/the-great-re-tagging-call-to-arms?s=1|2.2387) is episode 1.

Comment: Aw man, I would love to to help retag, but these are always planned at the worst possible times!

Comment: @DJM What would be the ideal time you could participate in?

Answer (score 4):

## TRE notes and tips

- Don't edit closed questions! (This is covered by the search, but just in case) The rationale, if you ask, is that **it's just not worth it**. You can spend the same time doing something better.
- Don't edit questions that you voted to close/flagged for closure. For the same reason I stated above.
- Please make substantial edits. Think of it like this: You *are* going to edit tags, but are going to try very hard to edit other stuff as well.
- These are the tags that need to applied to more questions: [backshifting](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backshifting), [quantifiers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantifiers), [tag-questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-questions). These are tags that *possibly* need to be applied to more questions: [modality](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modality), [case](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/case). (Add more if you see fit)
- These are the tags that need to be removed and be replaced with better ones: [meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning), [usage](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage), [phrase](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase), [paraphrase](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paraphrase). (Add more if you see fit)
- There are also common sightings of irrelevant application the [usage] and [meaning] family tags, such as [meaning-in-context](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context), [phrase-usage](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-usage) etc.
- If you think there's a need for a tag to be made, please discuss it in the chatroom.
- If you're ever doubtful what tags to add to a question, please discuss it in the chatroom.

### List of the questions [grammar](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) should remain on:

- [What is meant by "grammar"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/70700/what-is-meant-by-grammar)
- <Please add as you see fit>

### Here's how TRE will be done:

1. The people that participate will click on this shiny thingy: [I am a link](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3ano%20%5bgrammar%5d) which is a search query for non-closed questions with [grammar](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar), sorting "Newest".
2. Then they'll give me a number: "I'll retag **30** questions", for instance.
3. I'll tell them: Pick the first thirty questions! You should edit from this question: <a link> to this one: <a link>
4. They'll start editing.
5. Profit.
6. When we're done, better people than me that still want to retag will deal with closed questions with help me clean up the closed questions of the tag.

**Important tip:** Please open the links to the questions you want to edit in a new tab. If you open the link in the same tab and use the 'back' button, your results wouldn't be the same as the list and finding which questions you should've edited becomes hard.

Comment: I'm continuing what we did at Chem.SE. You can see what happened there [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2940/the-great-retagging-event-episode-1-the-one-taggers), though the topic is different.

Comment: If an ELL question tagged [tag:grammar] is also tagged with [tag:grammaticality] and/or [tag:sentence-meaning], I usually find that the [tag:grammaticality] and [tag:sentence-meaning] tags are also worth deleting.