# Grammar and gramma tag

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging, tag-request

I have just seen that there is [a question tagged gramma](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/310416/is-this-sentence-grammatically-correct-i-want-to-stress-how-grateful-i-am-f).

I believe that the [gramma](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gramma) tag should be deleted. Could a moderator perhaps do this?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for spotting this. It's fine just to suggest an edit replacing the tag ([grammar](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) is fine, but if you can, use more specific tags, as the tag excerpt indicates). I've edited it myself now; the system will [automatically remove unused tags after 24 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754/295232).

Comment: Have we abandoned the effort to do away with the "grammar", "grammaticality" etc. tags (I think there were 5)?

Comment: I'm not aware of anyone actively working on it. I sometimes replace it when I see it, but without coordinated effort (https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2811/18673) it is doomed to stay, regardless of what the excerpt says.

Comment: I might be the only one then. Whenever I see any of those tags I remove them