# Should we have a meta thread for "How to learn English quickly" tricks?

Tags: discussion

I can state two things with confidence:

1) Asking *"What are some good resources for learning English?"* is off-topic. However, we have a [meta thread devoted to that topic](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english).

2) *"What are some good ways to learn English quickly?"* is also [off-topic (as explained here)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106/how-can-i-ask-about-learn-tips-and-tricks). Yet we get asked that question rather often (understandably so, particularly by newcomers; see, for example, [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14825/how-to-learn-english-in-quick-way)).

I'm wondering if it might be worth starting a community thread, much like the resources thread, only it would be devoted to things that helped others learn English better or more quickly. That way, those who want to share a good trick will have a place to share it, and those who want to learn about such tricks will have an ELL resource where they can be pointed to.

Is there any reason why we should or shouldn't have such a meta thread? (If there seems to be much consensus that we should, maybe we can start one soon).

Comment: I think this is a terrific idea. I think it would not only be of value to our users, it would be a place where learners of every level of achievement could become more engaged in the site by contributing substantively. Or nominally. :)

Comment: What Stoney said! Excellent idea. We might consider dividing it into sections like our resources thread is. Perhaps speaking, reading, listening, writing etc.?

Comment: @WendiKidd - The only problem with that suggestion is that the resources thread is largely populated by links, whereas I believe this thread would be populated with narratives, so it might be harder to list several responses under a single answer.

Comment: This is an excellent idea. I'm a little concerned over how to keep it readable, however,  since it's likely to be long. Obviously it's trivial to maintain an index in the "question", but long posts of any sort on the Internet have unfortunate effects on attention spans. Also, it would need a large attention-getting disclaimer to the effect that *"yes, this is technically against the rules, but there's a good reason for it in this case. DO NOT point to this as an excuse for an inappropriate question of your own."*

Comment: Maybe we could replace *quickly* with some other adverb like *effectively*.

Comment: @snail - Either one works for me, although, of the questions falling under this category that I can remember, most of them seemed to focus on quick turnaround times. _"I want good English, and I want it now!"_ – that sort of thing.

Comment: I'm just a bit worried that newcomers won't find meta by themselves, and since a question on main can't be closed as a duplicate of a question on meta, we'll have to keep pointing them here manually.

Comment: I agree with @Reg, but at least we'll have a place to point them, instead of just closing the questions altogether.

Comment: I completely agree with all of the above ideas. I wish for an FAQ on "How to learn English" for a while. And, having several approaches, though potentially opinion-based ones, available for them to choose from is definitely a great resource for ELLs.