# Resources for learning English: should we have it at all?

Tags: discussion

This topic is a kind of survey to figure out if the ELL community would like to have a single, uniform Community Wiki question to keep all of the resources in a single place.

Since we are in the Beta, I guess we need a month so that a common consensus was found.

*I would ask diamond moderators to mark it* [featured](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured) *for a better promotion.*

#### Relevant links

- [What should our FAQ contain?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/what-should-our-faq-contain)
- [Alternative websites for proofreading](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263/alternative-websites-for-proofreading)

Comment: @kiamlaluno Would you please comment on your edit? I don't quite follow how it improved the question.

Comment: It has been pointed out before: Questions on meta should not be written as pools. Since it is a discussion, it is not fair to suggest what the users should say in their answers.

Comment: Is this question about having such CW question on the main site, or the meta site?

Answer (score 7):

Here's how I see it organized (voting is separate to the general idea, so I guess the score here will be lower than for the question ;)). Each section will eventually grow into a separate answer to a Comm.Wiki question.

In fact, check the [respective Comm.Wiki for Chinese.SE](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/resources-for-learning-mandarin-chinese) to see how it looks after some effort.

- **Books**

  - ...
- **Dictionaries Online**

  - [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/) dictionary search — search through N major dictionaries online;
  - ...
- **Tests and Assessments**

  - CEFR — where it is accepted, cost, availability, certified test centers, ...
  - IELTS
  - TOEFL
  - ...
- **Language-Specific sites**

  - For native **Chinese** speakers

    - Web Site 1 — contains free podcasts. Requires average level of comprehension;
    - Web Site 2 — first NN lessons are free; monthly subscription costs $X. Does not require an entry level;
    - ...
  - For native **Italian** speakers

    - ...
  - For native **Russian** speakers

    - ...
- **Other Resources**

  - Googling for a definition of a certain word: type **`define crocodile tears`** in a Google search field to find its definition;
  - [Omegle](http://omegle.com) — a chat with native speakers;
  - [Chat Roulette](http://chatroulette.com/) — a chat with native speakers;
  - [Lang-8](http://lang-8.com) is a **proofreading** website where you can write a journal post in English, and have your entry corrected by native speakers of English. In return, you're encouraged to correct journal posts written in the language that you're a native speaker of.
- **Didactic and Learning to Learn**

  - [How to measure my current level of English comprehension?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2520/what-is-the-official-criteria-to-measure-current-level-of-english)

    - What level is needed to work in ...?
    - What level is required to study in ...?
  - How to schedule my study?

Comment: Excellent. A similar CW is on [Meta ELU](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/list-of-general-references), but not regularly maintained.

Comment: @StoneyB IMO, the Chinese one looks better elaborated. :) Anyway, we will copy everything relevant.

Comment: The [Russian](http://russian.stackexchange.com/q/833/1177) site also has one, but it appears to be very similar to the Chinese one.

Comment: We have a CW like this on [Japanese Language & Usage](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese).  We refer to it fairly often!  It's been useful.

Comment: I'm not sure about Omegle and Chat Roulette. I tried using it once (followed the links here) and almost all the connections I got, the first question was **ASL**!

Answer (score -3):

Yet another thought, maybe worth a separate voting.

Provided that CW will exist, suggesting to endorse a policy of closing questions related to learning resources as dupes of the FAQ Comm.Wiki.

If a question is about resources, but not covered by Comm.Wiki, we wait for nice answers (and let people harvest some reputation) and **then** copy a good content to the Comm.Wiki and close an original question.

Please downvote this answer if you think that other questions should **not** be closed.

Comment: I do not think such questions should be closed, but I think any useful resources from the answers and comments should be added to the CW list.

Comment: The problem: who will do the copying?

Comment: @StoneyB That's the issue. If we agree that individual Q's should be closed in favor of CW, it's easy to define that close-voters copy first, and vote then. OTOH, it is not very fair to askers (at the moment they asked, it was not yet a dupe).

Comment: Sometimes an excellent answer, far better than the others, comes along several months or a year or two after the question was asked. Closing the questions would prevent such answers.