# Resources for learning English

Tags: discussion, faq, online-resources, resource-request

This is a specifically created Community Wiki which gathers resources for learning English and [it has been approved by the Community itself](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/316).

It should be clear that **the resources are not written by one user or only by the mods, but by whoever wants to contribute.**

Just write in the appropriate answer/section. If you have questions or concerns, [ask a Meta question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) so we don't clutter the comments. You can link your Meta question from the comments.

Questions regarding such resources are still allowed, but they will be closed as a duplicate of this question if they are too broad. Specific and on topic requests are welcome ([ask on Meta](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) if you're unsure about your question). Follow the instructions made in the question about how to post, what can be posted, etc.

---

#### Organization

- Each answer contains only one type of resource, and all resources of that type.
- If possible, state whether the material is directed towards a **beginner**, **intermediate** or **advanced** audience.
- **Do not** include links that lead to illegal content or sites that host such content. If you see any, please **flag for moderator attention**, select *other*, and specify the offending resource. It will be deleted as soon as a moderator sees the flag.
- Follow the [community rules on self-promotion](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).
- Please indicate whether each resource is free or paid and if registration is required.
- Do not post images. They would take too much space.
- Use descriptive links instead of bare URLs where possible.
- Add resources in **alphabetical order** so that they will be easier to find. Resources starting with non-Latin characters should go after the end of the alphabet.

*Note: New rules could be added in the future. Please [ask a Meta question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) if you think a rule should be added, removed, or changed.*

---

#### Index

- [Audio books](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english#737)
- [Blogs](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english#750)
- [Books](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english#736)
- [Browser add-ons](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english#738)
- [Corpora](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english#748)
- [Dictionaries](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english#739)
- [Finding a partner to exchange online](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english#953)
- [Newspapers](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english#740)
- [Online courses](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english#741)
- [Podcasts](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english#742)
- [Pronunciation](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english#1057)
- [Resources written in simple English](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english#1145)
- [Software](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english#743)
- [Television](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english#744)
- [Thesauri](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english#747)
- [Translation services](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english#749)
- [Vocabulary builders](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english#1000)
- [Websites](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english#746)
- [YouTube channels](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english#860)

Comment: Hmm, you classified in terms of the type of source, but it could be more useful to classify on the part of English that it addresses: Grammar, Pronunciation, and so on

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I'll cross-link to the ELU question [What are your favorite English tools?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/what-are-your-favorite-english-language-tools) Most, though arguably not all, of these are very useful for learners, too.

Comment: I was trying to search here for two necessary things but couldn't find. I need a very good dictionary that has lots of examples of how a word works in different sentences and with different prepositions. And I need an approved website that has English tests.

Comment: I would add to that list: closed captions in movies/series.

Comment: Would anyone add resources for reading comprehension, essay writing, literature (what you would learn at school)? Most books here happen to be about grammar!

Comment: @Cheng ELL is for learning the English language, not more advanced skills such as how to write an essay. There are other sites (such as [Writing SE](https://writing.stackexchange.com/) and [Literature SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/)) that cover those topics.

Answer (score 23):

### Dictionaries

Dictionaries are useful for finding definitions, spellings, pronunciations, and usage examples.

#### Learner's dictionaries

English learner's dictionaries, as their name indicates, are focused on the particular needs of English language learners; they may have fewer entries than other dictionaries, but usually provide more extensive examples, usage notes, and related phrases.

- [Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English](http://www.ldoceonline.com/)
- [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/)
- [Collins COBUILD](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/)
- [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/)
- [Cambridge Learner's Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/learner-english/)
- [Merriam-Webster's Learner's Dictionary](http://learnersdictionary.com/)

#### Idioms, expressions, and slang

Many common idiomatic expressions may be found in standard dictionaries; these websites provide access to a larger and more thoroughly treated collection:

- [TFD Idioms and Phrases](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/) - From TheFreeDictionary, a searchable database of idioms from the *Cambridge International Dictionary of Idioms* and the *Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms*.
- [The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/) — Provides meanings and origins of numerous English expressions and sayings, with commentary by Gary Martin.

For dialectical English, a standard reference is Joseph Wright's *The English Dialect Dictionary, being the complete vocabulary of all dialect words still in use, or known to have been in use during the last two hundred years...*, OUP 1898-1905. Available at archive.org: [A-C](https://archive.org/stream/englishdialectdi01wriguoft), [D-G](https://archive.org/details/cu31924088038397), [H-L](https://archive.org/stream/englishdialectdi03wriguoft), [M-Q](https://archive.org/stream/englishdialectdi04wriguoft), [R-S](https://archive.org/details/cu31924088038421), [T-Z](https://archive.org/stream/englishdialectdi06wriguoft)

The use of slang, especially by a language learner, is somewhat fraught— what is acceptable in what situations is highly contextual and varies depending on numerous cultural conventions and social cues. Moreover, slang by its nature is informal and rapidly changing, making it difficult to compile into a reference. For those interested in understanding how slang is used, however, resources include the following:

- [Green's Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/) — Jonathon Green's 2010 magnum opus, the peerless GDoS is now available online with a subscription.
- [Online Slang Dictionary](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/) – edited by Walter Rader

#### General-purpose dictionaries

Full-length, general-purpose dictionaries are aimed at providing reasonably comprehensive coverage of the language mostly for native speakers. Online versions of dictionaries from the following publishers are commonly cited at ELL.SE:

- [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/)
- [Cambridge Dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/)
- [Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/)
- [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/)

#### Dictionary meta-references

Several sites either link out to multiple references, or provide merged results from the references directly. These can be useful for comparing definitions and usage notes across sources.

- [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/)
- [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/)
- [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/)
- [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/)

#### Etymology and history

- The [Oxford English Dictionary (OED)](http://www.oed.com) – The undisputed leading historical dictionary of English, showing the development of word meanings, including obsolete and obscure meanings, from the advent of English itself. A subscription is required, although free access is available via many libraries and universities.

  - The first edition, published between 1884 and 1928 as the *New English Dictionary*, is in the public domain and available at archive.org:
    [A–B](http://archive.org/details/oed01arch), [C](http://archive.org/details/oed02arch), [D–E](http://archive.org/details/oed03arch), [F–G](http://archive.org/details/oed04arch), [H–K](http://archive.org/details/newenglishdict05murrmiss), [L](http://archive.org/details/oed6aarch), [M–N](http://archive.org/details/oed6barch), [O–P](http://archive.org/stream/oed07arch), [Q–R](http://archive.org/details/oed8aarch), [S-Sh](http://archive.org/stream/oed8barch#page/n5/mode/2up), [Si–St](http://archive.org/details/oed9aarch), [Su–Th](http://archive.org/details/oed9barch), [Ti–U](http://archive.org/details/oedxaarch), [V–Z](http://archive.org/details/oedxbarch)
- [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://etymonline.com/) - An extensive free compilation of word origins compiled by Douglas Harper, based on the OED and other sources

#### Other

- [The New Hacker's Dictionary](http://catb.org/%7Eesr/jargon/html/index.html) - A dictionary of computer programming jargon.
- [MDic](http://mdic.gnufolks.org/) - a free, cross-platform English dictionary from GNU
- Wiktionary - a crowd-sourced dictionary in [English](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Main_Page), and in [other languages](http://www.wiktionary.org/).
- [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/) - a crowd-sourced dictionary of slang, with entries of highly variable quality and accuracy
- [*A Pronouncing Dictionary of American English*](https://archive.org/details/pronouncingdicti00unse/page/n5/mode/2up?view=theater), by Kenyon and Knott. G.C. Merriam & Co, 1949. **Only** pronunciations, in [American English phonemic alphabet](http://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/modestproposal.pdf), like the English  pronunciations in bilingual dictionaries.

Answer (score 17):

### Books

- *[The Cambridge Guide to English Usage](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/052162181X)* *by Pam Peters*
- *[Practical English Usage](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0194202437)* *by Michael Swan* - A popular pedagogical grammar.  It's informed by modern linguistic analysis, but it's presented in a way that is useful for learners. It's also available [online](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/grammar/practical-english-usage).
- *[A Practical English Grammar](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0194313425)* *by Thomson and Martinet*
- *[Essential Grammar in Use with Answers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521675804) (Beginner-Elementary level)* *by Raymond Murphy*
- *[Style: Lessons in Clarity and Grace](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0205747469)* *by Joseph M. Williams and Gregory G. Colomb*
- *[Longman Grammar of Spoken and Written English](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0582237254)* *by Douglas Biber, Stig Johansson, et al.*
- *[The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468)* (CGEL) - The most recent and comprehensive descriptive grammar of Standard English.  Although this book is technical and is *not* designed to be used directly by language learners, it's a valuable resource for anyone who wants to write more accurate answers.  [Chapters one and two](http://www.cambridge.org/uk/linguistics/cgel/sample.htm) are available for free online. A shorter version aimed at undergraduate students with no background in linguistics is [A Student's Introduction to English Grammar](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521612888).
- *[The New English File series](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0194384330)* - A series of textbooks for every level of English.
- [High School Grammar and Composition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/8121900093) - Wren and Martin, Prentice Hall

Comment: What's the most respected and the most proper grammar book nowadays?

Comment: @SovereignSun CGEL is probably one of the most vetted modern grammar books. However, it's rather *sui generis*, that is, what you read from that book might be entirely different from what you have learned.

Answer (score 12):

### Websites

- [BBC Learning English](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/) Doesn't attempt to cover *everything*, but the things it does cover are nicely organised into "bite-sized chunks" that you can easily dip in to without getting bored or overloaded.
- [The English Club](https://www.englishclub.com/) - "everything from grammar for learners to worksheets for teachers, including fun pages like games, videos, quizzes and chat." The [Grammar Guide](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/index.htm) is especially good for beginners.
- [English Online France](http://cla-tice2.univ-fcomte.fr/eolf/)-
  Resources for students and teachers of English as a foreign language.(Listening exercises,pronunciation exercises, grammar exercises) instructions are in English.
- [Really Learn English](http://www.really-learn-english.com/free-learn-to-speak-english.html) *Learn to Speak English* website
- [The KISS Grammar Site](http://www.kissgrammar.org/) - Instead of focusing on grammatical constructions, the KISS Approach focuses on texts. It uses grammatical concepts to explain how words in a sentence work together to create meaning. Check out the [Welcome Page](http://www.kissgrammar.org/KISS_Int.htm) and [Printable KISS Grammar Books](http://www.kissgrammar.org/kiss/wb/PBooks/index.htm).
- [VOA Learning English](http://learningenglish.voanews.com/) - "We are American English" - Comprehensive Learning English website that divides written and audio content by levels and topic. A **must use** site for those interested in contemporary American English, Idioms and Culture.
- [Guide to Grammar & Writing. Dedicated to the memory of Dr. Charles Darling.](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/index.htm)
- [HiNative multilingual Q&A site](https://hinative.com/) - a free interactive site where speakers of many languages and any fluency level can ask and/or answer questions about English. It has equivalent sections for Spanish, Japanese, etc. Supports images and audible attachments, and has separate sections for cultural questions. Registration required; minor extra features available to paid subscribers.
- [Lousy Writer](http://www.lousywriter.com/) - This site isn't designed for EFL learners, but it does favor "plain English" and has a lot of quick tips on a wide range of subjects from the parts of speech to writing a love letter.
- [Quizlet](http://www.quizlet.com/) - A good website for mastering any kind of vocabulary. It can be very helpful for ELL.

Comment: You might want to add mention of my Encyclopedic Dictionary of Mercan English, which uses Esperanto as its interface language. Access to the dictionary is completely open. There is no registration of any kind required. The url is http://prof-vortaro-de-la-merk-angla.weebly.com/.

Answer (score 11):

### Blogs

- [The English Blog](http://www.englishblog.com/learning_english/) Internet resources, reviews, news, tips and trivia for teachers and learners of English.
- [Caxton. Mostly language, but not always](http://caxton1485.wordpress.com/)
- [Common Errors in English Usage](http://public.wsu.edu/%7Ebrians/errors/errors.html#w)
- [I Study English](http://www.istudyenglish.org/#herepagestarts) lists a lot of vocabulary words
- [Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/) Grammar and usage
- [Literal-Minded. Linguistic commentary from a guy who takes things too literally](http://literalminded.wordpress.com/)
- [Motivated Grammar. Prescriptivism Must Die!](http://motivatedgrammar.wordpress.com/)

Answer (score 10):

### Exchanging online with a partner

- [Find a Discord server](https://discordservers.com/search/Learn%20English) Discord is free a voice and text chat program that has many public servers dedicated to helping people learn a foreign language.
- [Italki](http://www.italki.com/) This website features thousands of native English speakers who will do **free** language exchange with non-native speakers and who will correct texts that you write.
- [Language Exchanges](http://www.language-exchanges.org/) - A site where you can find people to practice English with on Skype
- [Polyglott club](http://polyglotclub.com/help/polyglot-club/polyglot-club-what) Allows you to learn and practice foreign languages worldwide. Members can share their knowledge and ideas about any language or culture, whether online (Online Exchange) or face-to-face (Offline Exchange). Free.

Answer (score 10):

### Pronunciation

- Many Internet dictionaries provide recorded pronunciations: [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/), [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/), [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english), [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/), [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/), [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Main_Page), and others.
- There is also [Forvo.com](http://www.forvo.com), which allows you to enter a word and hear it pronounced by everyday people. While dictionaries usually have more "neutral" pronunciations, Forvo can be good for letting you hear regional tendencies, local accents, and individual variations.
- [inogolo](http://www.inogolo.com/) - This site bills itself as a "website devoted to the English pronunciation of the names of people, places, and miscellaneous stuff."
- Another choice is [IVONA TTS](http://www.ivona.com/us/). [It has a free app for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ivona.tts.voicebeta.eng.usa.kendra), and several voices in various English dialects. You can use it to listen to the new words and their example sentences. You can also listen to the interesting news and texts to improve listening skills. I use it in combination with a ["Voice reading"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.noinnion.android.voicereading) app.
- A section of the British Library website called [Sounds Familiar?](http://www.bl.uk/learning/langlit/sounds/index.html) has many recordings of contemporary British dialects and interesting discussions of current trends in British speech.
- At [YouGlish](https://youglish.com/), when the user enters an English phrase, the site creates a playlist of YouTube videos containing that phrase cued to a few seconds before it, with the dialogue text below. It's useful for hearing many native speakers say the same phrase naturally.

Comment: What are some good materials on mouth shape and tongue position in pronunciation?

Answer (score 9):

### Vocabulary builders

[Wordly Wise 3000](http://www.wordlywise3000.com/word_lists/?book=02&lesson=1) – Learn more than 3000 advanced words (good for SAT).

[The General Service List](http://jbauman.com/gsl.html) – The most common 2284 English words.

[Spelling Through Morphographs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0026848651) by Robert Dixon and Seigfried Engelmann.  Designed as a one-year supplement to an English class for students who are already familiar with English.  Teaches the prefixes, roots, and suffixes that make up English words, and encourages students to play with combining them to make valid words.  Teaches spelling and vocabulary, plus a bit of grammar.

[Word of The Hour](https://wordofthehour.org/) – A tool that features one basic English language vocabulary word every hour with an active community on Reddit.  For more advanced vocabulary words, see [FunWithWords](https://www.reddit.com/r/funwithwords/).

[Word Menu](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Random_House_Webster_s_Word_Menu/A0DYAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0&bsq=word%20menu%20glazier) by Stephen Glazier; A unique dictionary that is organized by subject

Comment: The links look to be self-serving.  The books4languages website is currently in Beta, the company is a startup business, it appears to only have 10 employees https://www.internshipmapper.com/en/employers/5299-mls-slu This is a page meant for established and reliable resources, not for semi-unknown companies. I have no choice but to roll back the edits.

Comment: ok. so, you understand if a company is reliable or not by the size, not the quality? very good. thanks.

Comment: @books4languages.com. This page is reserved for established reliable resources that can be easily accessed or bought. I looked at the B4L website quite carefully before deciding to roll the edit back. There are hundreds of EFL and TEFL coursebooks available online and in bookstores. It would be impossible to list them all here. Moreover, a **vocabulary builder** is a book or resource that focuses on incrementing a learner's vocabulary. The series of coursebooks (but I didn't see where you could purchase them) offered by B4L are not specific to building one's vocabulary.

Answer (score 7):

### YouTube channels

- [iswearenglish](http://www.youtube.com/user/iswearenglish?feature=watch) - more than 2000 short videos for English learners
- [Stuff You Should Know](http://www.youtube.com/user/joshandchuck) - learn how different things work and learn English by the way
- [Master Spoken English](https://www.youtube.com/user/huyenmai0109?feature=watch) - a series of videos to help master pronunciation

Answer (score 6):

### Corpora

- [English-Corpora.org](http://www.english-corpora.org/) including:

  - [British National Corpus (BNC)](http://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/)
  - [Corpus of Canadian English (STRATHY)](http://www.english-corpora.org/can/)
  - [Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)](http://www.english-corpora.org/coca/)
  - [Corpus of Global Web-based English (GloWbE)](http://www.english-corpora.org/glowbe/)
  - [Corpus of Historical American English](http://www.english-corpora.org/coha/)
  - [Time Magazine Corpus](http://www.english-corpora.org/time/)
- [Corpus Concordance English](http://lextutor.ca/conc/eng/)
- [Google Books Ngram Viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams)

Answer (score 6):

### On-Line Commercial Resources:

- [Really Learn English product catalog](http://store.really-learn-english.com/collections/all)

Answer (score 6):

### Resources written in simple English:

- [Simple English Wikipedia](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page)
- [Special English VOA](http://learningenglish.voanews.com/)

Answer (score 5):

### Machine Translation

- [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/)
- [Microsoft (Bing) Translator](http://www.bing.com/translator)
- [Free Translation](https://www.freetranslation.com/)

Comment: My only question was downvoted and maybe that's why I can't edit this. But add the https://www.deepl.com/en/translator

Answer (score 4):

### Podcasts

- [ESLPod](http://www.eslpod.com/) - English-as-a-second-language [podcast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Podcast)

Answer (score 3):

### Audio books

- [BITS English Language Learning](http://esl-bits.net/) - Site's purpose: to help students improve their listening and reading comprehension of the English language. English Language Learners will find many suitable audiobooks there.
- [Librivox](http://librivox.org/) - Public domain audiobooks read by volunteers, freely available
- [Wired for Books](http://www.wiredforbooks.org) - on line educational project of the WOUB Center for Public Media at Ohio University in Athens, Ohio.
  (Features author interviews, dramatic audio productions of classic literature, readings of poetry, short stories, lectures, essays, and children's literature.
- [Lit2Go](http://etc.usf.edu/lit2go/collections/) - a collection of children's literature. You can find several familiar stories and novels along with some poems here. All come with audio and Flesch–Kincaid Readability Level. Special thanks go to autumn season in [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/76922/3281).

Answer (score 3):

### Online courses

- [Duolingo](https://www.duolingo.com/) - Learn English (and many other languages) with elements of gamification for free.

Comment: A very poor way to "learn a language." In fact, all you are doing is remembering grammar constructs, devoid of any real world, meaningful context  so Duolingo is extremely limited in its usefulness.

Comment: @AlanCarmack While it may not be ideal as the sole learning tool, it encourages daily practice of the grammar and vocabulary while permitting the user to learn at his own pace. This is probably most beneficial when used in addition to other resources; e.g., talking to people, reading articles or watching the news, films, &c., in order to bring context to the newly learned grammar concepts. In any case, I have found it very useful for studying Russian.

Answer (score 3):

### Software

- [Anki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anki_(software)) is a spaced repetition [flashcard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flashcard) program.
- [Artha](https://sourceforge.net/projects/artha/), a  free cross-platform English thesaurus that works off-line, and exists in portable (USB drive) version
- [HiNative](http://www.hinative.com), a mobile app with a community (also listed under [Websites](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english#746))

Answer (score 3):

### Television

- [Hulu](http://www.hulu.com/) - Streaming video site (within United States)
- [Netflix](https://signup.netflix.com/) - Streaming video and movies site (*may not be accessible in all areas*)
- [BBC iPlayer](http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer) - Streaming video and radio (within United Kingdom)

Answer (score 3):

### Thesauruses (or Thesauri)

Note most dictionary websites contain a section that has a thesaurus. See [Dictionaries](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/739/).

- [Big Huge Thesaurus](http://words.bighugelabs.com/) - includes similar terms. "sounds like" and rhymes as well as synonyms and antonyms. Entries are based on source data from the Princeton University WordNet database, the Carnegie Mellon Pronouncing Dictionary, and suggestions from thousands of people on the internet.
- [The Free Thesaurus](http://www.freethesaurus.com/) - a section of [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dictionary.htm)
- [Merriam-Webster’s Dictionary of Synonyms](http://books.google.com/books?id=8N4UReTJYhUC) - explanations of the differences between closely related words
- [Merriam-Webster online thesaurus](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/)
- [Thesaurus.com](http://thesaurus.com/)

Answer (score 2):

### Browser add-ons

- Add the resources here in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 2):

### Newspapers

- [Google News](https://news.google.com/) - Read and search articles from many newspapers
- [New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/)
- [Sydney Morning Herald](http://www.smh.com.au/) - News about Australia and the world
- [Yahoo News](http://news.yahoo.com/) - Read and search articles from many newspapers
- [The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/) - News written in simple and clear English
- [The Wall Street Journal](http://online.wsj.com/home-page) - Not necessarily the simplest English, but extremely well-written
- [The Higher Learning](http://thehigherlearning.com/) - shortened, simplified versions of the news for young readers

Answer (score 1):

## Android Apps

[Duolingo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.duolingo)

[Grammar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mng.com.englishgrammar)