# Congratulations! English Language Learners is graduating!

Tags: discussion, graduation

It's a big day. You've been cleared for graduation by the Stack Exchange Community Team! English Language Learners has already met our threshold for [graduation-worthy sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites), and today joins in the new design-independent graduation process! Reaching 'mature community' status is a big milestone, and you should be very proud.

You've only just completed the election to celebrate this, but now you will receive the remaining benefits detailed in this process as well, which include:

- You will no longer see the "beta" label attached to your site's name
- You will become eligible for question migration paths with the rest of the network
- You will be able to select your own community ads

In the coming months, the site will receive a full design from one of our designers, which will be packaged with an increase in the amount of reputation needed to access each privilege. It's no secret that our backlog for site designs is long, and although you're looking at wait of several months, we wanted to [give you the things we could give](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation) you now. There are also bound to be bugs as the new process gets rolled out so if you come across anything out of place, please report it on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) using the [graduating-sites] tag.

This site has reached this point because of your generous contributions. Together, you've created a valuable resource that helps people. Congratulations on all you've accomplished.

Comment: Question - will this increase in rep required to access each privilege affect those we've already qualified for? For example, if $privilege is currently unlocked at 1500 rep, and this is increased to 2000 rep, would I lose that privilege?

Comment: @Damien You would, yes.

Comment: First, I got elected as a moderator, and in a couple of days, this graduation. Feeling awesome! It all came apropos.... :)

Comment: @MaulikV Congrats! And congratz to ELL!!

Comment: Congratulations, @MaulikV-ji! (0:

Answer (score 14):

We've had [ups](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/924/happy-birthday-ell?s=1|2.8626) and [downs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUCa8.png). Sometimes we had to take a step back and see [what's wrong](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/robo-reviewers-on-ell). Most of the times we had to [nudge our askers to do](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) or [ask them](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/904/requests-for-native-speakers-to-answer-questions) to stop doing something. Sometimes we had to make sure [we're helping learners](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1160/have-we-forgotten-our-mission) and sometimes it was just some [advice](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) to the learners. Oh, and we occasionally try to gather [useful](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263/alternative-websites-for-proofreading) [sources](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english) for learners, even if that isn't driving traffic to ELL.

We worked hard to build something that'd be there for English Language Learners. Now we've succeeded. Now, teachers like StoneyB, J.R., Snailboat, Kiam and many others can celebrate and take a moment to clean off their sweat. The journey still continues, and we'll see more and more awesome people here, but for now, **congratulations to ELL for being an awesome community**.

I was late to the party. But ELL has been one of my friends ever since. I should probably exclude myself from the "we", since I haven't been for ELL as much I should have. But I still wave my hands from the far, and clap when I should.

[image]
<sub><sub>[Source](http://www.remarkableriverrun.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/20-thank-you.jpg)</sub></sub>

Answer (score 8):

#### Not sure exactly when it happened, but the beta label is gone. Hurrah!

[image: No more Beta!]