# Happy 10th, English Language Learners!

Tags: discussion

It’s been 10 years since this site was [proposed in Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners), so we’re celebrating ELL’s 10th anniversary!

In the beginning, this site was started by users of [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) (EL&U), as a place for all the questions from learners that didn’t quite fit there. Thus, a new site was born to better serve those questions and their answers. While ELL remains linked to EL&U (for example, via [migrated questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247902/323179)), ELL has really flourished as its own site.

Ten years is a long time, and we appreciate all the people who have been here from the start, and also those who have joined along the way. Feel free to share your thoughts and stories in the answers and comments.

We’ve compiled some birthday-related posts to help you [get in the birthday spirit](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+into+the+spirit+of):

- [Is the using of "present" and "gift" considered a matter of style?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/159262/41273)
- [What does "Candygram" mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/174724/41273)
- ["a ten years old boy" or "a ten year old boy"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/6434/41273)
- [What is the verbal phrase for "making a candle stop burning"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/236527/41273)
- [Why do native speakers say 'Come on in' rather than 'Come in'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/155385/41273)

[image: Iconic ELL banner bearing the text 'ELL 10 years!']

Answer (score 7):

The [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/03/06/five-stack-exchange-sites-turned-ten-years-old-this-quarter/?cb=1) celebrating the 10 year anniversary of a number of sites (including ELL) is live.

A post celebrating ELL’s first birthday popped up in the sidebar and I wanted to make sure folks noticed it: [Happy Birthday ELL](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/924/9161). We’ve gone from just under 4000 users to 140,000 users and 6500 visits a day to 9400 visits, according to the site statistics at https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic

The community has helped a lot of people over the past 10 years. I know it has helped me understand my native language better. One of my favorite questions is [Why "grand theft auto", not "grand auto theft"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/96757/9161) because it made me realize that I don’t know the “why” for a lot of English questions even though I know the correct way to say something.

Comment: We should be getting a special banner soon to promote this post. But also, thanks for being here for the site!

Comment: Congratulations to you all! I've enjoyed hearing some of the stories of your community and love these additional stats and question that ColleenV posted. I hope to hear more stories in the future. I love hearing these.