# Is there a resource list post here?

Tags: discussion

Last time I posted a question and someone replied with a link on this website listing English learning resourced. However my question couldn't be found any more. So can I ask where is the resource list ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for this [question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english) from the ELL.Meta:

> *This is a specifically created Community Wiki which gathers resources for learning English and it has been approved by the Community
>   itself.*
>
> *It should be clear that the resources are not written by one user or only by the mods, but by whoever wants to contribute.*

Happy learning!