# Is it permanent suspension, or temporal one?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

[image]

I’ve got suspended. Will I be forever suspended?
I appreciate those who has helped me by now, especially James K, Kate Bunting and Michael Harvey. You will be remembered in my mind forever. Thank you all.

Comment: "Will I be forever suspended?" What did the information in the links say?

Comment: Related: [How to salvage questions](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2530/how-to-salvage-improve-questions-a-guide-by-example)

Comment: I don't know if the link in the announcement, Help Center, directs you to the relevant page but if it doesn't here it is: [Why are questions no longer being accepted by this account?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) the relevant section is here: *The ban will be lifted automatically by the system **when it determines that your positive contributions outweigh** the cost of those questions which were poorly received.*

Comment: In other words, improve your existing questions in such a way that the community finds them clear, understandable and **useful** when that is achieved the questions should earn **upvotes**. How many of your questions need to be upvoted to unblock the question ban? Unfortunately nobody knows that number, only the system does (NOT THE USERS OR MODS). Only the system can undo/reverse the question ban.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Thank you. I think it’s harder than getting zero votes.

Comment: @Mari-LouA is right; for some more information, you can also visit [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.