# Picture dictionaries with audio CDs

Tags: discussion

I am looking for picture dictionaries that enclose audio CDs (for my pre-school children).
I checked the dictionaries listed below:

- "The usborne Picture Dictionary" (Usborne Pub): This dictionary has an audio CD but that CD contains only the headwords.
- "4000 Essential English Words with Answer Key" series (Compass Publishing): This book has dictionary-like word definitions, and encloses an audio CD with headwords and definitions. But the pictures in this book are too small for my children, and from my point of view, the pictures are not really consistent with the headwords.
- "Oxford Reading Tree Dictionary" (Oxford University Press): This book has word definitions with large pictures, and encloses an audio CD with headwords and definitions. But it doesn't appeal to my children...

Do you have any recommendations for picture dictionaries that encloses audio CDs that contains headwords and definitions, and large pictures (especially suitable for pre-school children)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resources for learning English](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english)

Comment: I had a look through that topic, but I couldn't find any answers about the **Picture** dictionary for **children**. I am looking for that.