# can I ask my explanation about the video that I embed or link?

Tags: feature-request

My major problem that I feel I have is framing a proper sentence while conversing. that too when I want to respond during the conversation with the proper and meaningful reply.

So I think I could improve it if somebody corrects it then and there. But this is not possible. instead I can embed a video of few seconds (not more than 30 sec) and describe the video on context, content and story. then the stackexchange community helps me by correcting my mistake. I improve English lot faster I believe.

Is this a new feaure I am looking for? or is it already available? is it allowed post such way of question?

Answer (score 2):

While I'm sure that would be helpful for you, tutoring individual learners is outside the scope of ELL. There are some suggestions in the [Exchanging online with a partner](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/953/) answer to the [Resources for learning English thread](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/735/) that might be helpful.

I like the ["Learn a Lang" discord server](https://discordapp.com/invite/v5egjjJ) listed in that answer because it has both voice chat and text, and you may be able to help people learning your native language as well as get help learning English.