# Can I submit a video here for feedback on my pronunciation?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic, asking-questions

I am trying to improve my pronunciation of English words. For these purposes, I make short videos. That is, I want to know not about a specific word, but in general how understandable my speech is.
My question is this: can I drop a link to my YouTube videos here to get feedback?

P.S. For moderators: I am very sorry if I violate the rules of this site, but I just registered and did not find information on whether it is possible to drop links to videos here for feedback.

Comment: No, such a question would be proofreading.  See [ask]

Comment: Related questions: https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5312/9161 https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4660/9161