# English course for support position?

Tags: discussion, online-resources, resource-request

I'm looking to improve my English skills as a support person working for an IT company through live chat, can you recommend a series of videos or a youtube channel that can help me with that? All I can find is how to learn English from the start but I want something advanced for my specialty. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Requests for specific outside resources are regarded as off-topic because responses will merely be a matter of opinion. But why not read blogs, articles, and books devoted to your specialty? That would certainly broaden your vocabulary in the area.

Comment: Yes, go to UTube and google key words in you specialty. Listen to the techies talking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resources for learning English](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english)