# How can I find partner for English conversation?

Tags: discussion, resource-request

I am searching for partner who can speak with me English.

I searched websites that match people for learning English, but couldn't find any person.

Where I can find partners?

Comment: Are you looking for live meetings, then add your location. Or do you want to converse online or by phone? Are you willing to pay? Please [edit] your question and add all essential information.

Comment: Besides the resources mentioned in the canonical post, you can also converse in Stack Exchange site chats about your favorite topics. Depending on the site they have various levels of activity and it's almost always a moderated and pretty safe and friendly environment. [ELL](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24938/language-overflow) has one such 'main' chat and so does ELU, and other SE communities ranging from chemistry to cryptocurrency. Feel free to look around :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Resources for learning English](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/735/9161) thread here on ELL's Meta has a section of recommendations for [finding a partner online](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/953/9161).