# Is there a way to measure progress in grammar skills?

Tags: discussion

I want to learn about all basic aspects of English grammar. I already has a book and tests, but It wouldn't track the progress in my opinion.

For example, like in IELTS you can track your listening skills by doing same form of exam every time and see how your score grows. I want to find something like this, may be some international exam but specifically for grammar.

Comment: @Lambie is there a part of stackexchange where I can ask this question? I thought this one is about learning english

Comment: I don't think so. There are tons and tons of paying and non-paying grammar sources online. But the important thing is to go step by step. Here are some: https://www.fluentu.com/blog/english/learn-english-grammar-online/

Comment: Related: [Resources for learning English](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english)

Answer (score 1):

I know for a fact that Duolingo has a feature called *Progress quiz*, which is (irony up ahead) a quiz that tracks your progress by grading you, as you study and take the quiz repeatedly. I'm not sure whether this is your idea of tracking progress, but it sure is something.