# Idiomatic American English resources

Tags: discussion, resource-request

I'd like to improve my spoken English and thought *maybe* it was a good start to learn how to have a proper conversation, or order a meal in a restaurant, or going into a shop and ask for help for instance.

My problem is I don't find idiomatic American English courses which features such in-context trainings, does anyone have URLs to websites or books I could read to improve?

Comment: The Resources for learning English thread has a section for [Exchanging online with a partner](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english#953) that might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you @ColleenV that does answer my question, if you want to turn your comment into an answer I'd be glad to accept it :)

Comment: This question shows the main problem with SE. How can a question like this receive anything other than advice? Personally, I'm fine with that, but not the site, apparently. Or doesn't it matter in META??

Answer (score -1):

Why not watch some movies, TV shows, or even YouTube videos where Americans do those things? (I think it's a good idea too, if your goal is to improve your situational skills in English: I do the same to improve my French and German.) Of course it should not be your *only* source to study.

Comment: I agree with your recommendation, but perhaps it should have been a comment.

Comment: @Wehage It actually was a comment first, but I changed it since I think it does answer the question. Certainly other more robust answers are possible.