# Alternative for Vocabulary.com

Tags: discussion

I recently find the website vocabulary.com. It helped me a lot to memorize a great number of words, and also mastering its spelling, but unfortunately it doesn't allowed to submit a list of expressions. Do anyone know a website that provide this service, I mean submitting a list of expression and memorize it by spelling it several times . thanks in advance

Comment: apparently vocabulary.com does this already: "Just want to ace tomorrow’s vocabulary quiz? Create your own list of words to study. Vocabulary lists are easy to make, share, and learn."

Comment: Yes I know I can enter a text, but the website choose the convenient word for learning. But what I ask for, is to learn an expression, not a single word, for example the expressions that are followed by gerund or infinitive, idioms ...

Comment: I don’t know if this question is suited to SE exactly, but (and I’m sorry if this will annoy someone in the future), I’m upvoting it because it’s in good faith and I’d like to see it answered.

Comment: Sounds like you should buy "expressions.com" and get coding!   (price is only Price is only $86,250.00)

Comment: If I had an advancend level in programing, I woudn't post this post :))

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Resources for learning English](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/735/36187). Might be worth updating it with some of these answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Quizlet is perfect for this!

Head to [www.quizlet.com](https://www.quizlet.com) and you can sign up for an account, create a list of vocabulary words and play the `Spell` game in your word set.

Answer (score 0):

> the expressions that are followed by gerund or infinitive, idioms

I suppose what you are asking for  is a list of verbs that take the infinitive and those that take a gerund.

**Example**

*I like going to the beach.*

*I want to go to the beach.*

Unfortunately it is not a simple as that. You can say either:

*I like to go to the beach* OR *I like going to the beach.*

but you cannot say, "I want going to the beach." (incorrect)

---

I suggest searching online for *which verbs use gerunds and infinitives*

Here is just one example I found [https://www.tolearnenglish.com/exercises/exercise-english-2/exercise-english-85423.php#:~:text=The%20gerund%20has%20the%20same%20form%20as%20the,postpone%2C%20practise%2C%20recall%2C%20regret%2C%20resent%2C%20risk%2C%20stop%2C%20suggest](https://www.tolearnenglish.com/exercises/exercise-english-2/exercise-english-85423.php#:%7E:text=The%20gerund%20has%20the%20same%20form%20as%20the,postpone%2C%20practise%2C%20recall%2C%20regret%2C%20resent%2C%20risk%2C%20stop%2C%20suggest).

**Note** I haven't checked that site for correctness and it looks rather amateurish in design.