# Grammar books for native speaker?

Tags: discussion, resource-request

As a well-read native speaker, I know what “sounds right”, but I often don’t know the formal terminology or rules to explain *why* to a learner.

Are there any grammar books or other resources that can help me write better answers here without being either too basic for a native speaker or too academic for a casual reader?

Comment: You have been a good contributor as long as I have observed and yet try to improve furthermore? Just admirable.

Answer (score 5):

*[The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language)* (CGEL), Huddleston and Pullum, 2002, a very often cited reference book in these here parts (ELL and ELU). I don't know remotely as much about CGEL as some knowledgeable contributors, and I only consult it and reference it when I need to, but it is one of the most comprehensive and coherent grammars. Note that from what I understand it is not without issues and doesn't always agree with other major grammar reference books.

This [canonical meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/736/61125) includes some other useful grammars.

Comment: I appreciate the pointer to the canonical list, but before spending $40, I want to be sure I’m picking the right one for my level/needs.

Comment: @StephenS I was going to say "Steal a peek on Google Books", but unfortunately there is no preview available for this particular book. Huddleston and Pullum also have a simplified grammar that's available [for preview](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Student_s_Introduction_to_English_Gram/qlxDqB4ldx4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=cambridge+grammar+of+the+english+language&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: Oops, it’s the “simplified” one that’s $40; the full one is $300. Ouch!

Comment: @EddieKal: I saw your comment yesterday but wasn't able to reply for some reason. Yes, it's been deleted for copyright infringement. I found another free copy (way better than the previous one) [here](https://dokumen.pub/qdownload/the-cambridge-grammar-of-the-english-language-1316423530-9781316423530.html). I think you should also add the link to your answer. :)

Comment: @Void Haha, you are ever so resourceful! Thanks!! I think these links are subject to removal, so let's keep them in the comments. Hope this one stays longer.

Answer (score 4):

Huddleston and Pullum's [*Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*](https://www.cambridge.org/de/academic/subjects/languages-linguistics/grammar-and-syntax/cambridge-grammar-english-language?format=HB) (1860 pages) is a grammar reference aimed primarily at linguists.

For mere mortals, I recommend [*Cambridge Grammar of English: A Comprehensive Guide*](https://www.cambridge.org/de/cambridgeenglish/catalog/grammar-vocabulary-and-pronunciation/cambridge-grammar-english) by Ronald Carter and Michael McCarthy (Cambridge University Press, 2006), which is also much more affordable.

Answer (score 3):

CGEL is popular with many users, but [McCawley](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/McCawley-Lg.pdf) 1998 is an alternative that is completely clear and well-written (by one person), with all deviations from traditional terminology explained as they occur, and no made-up terminology. It's a generative grammar, but not a Chomskyan grammar. McCawley gives top billing to the grammatical phenomena of the title, and only second billing to the theory he uses to describe them.

- McCawley, James D. [*The Syntactic Phenomena of English*](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Syntactic_Phenomena_of_English.html?id=k6-C5AWWqjQC).
  2nd edition 1998. University of Chicago Press

One nice feature is that McCawley 1998 is available as a paperback that can be held and used with one hand.