# Does anyone knows a good podcasts or youtube channel that teaches basic English up to intermediate English for free?

Tags: discussion, resource-request, online-resources

It doesn’t matter if it is British or American English

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! Your question is a resource request and thus off-topic on the main site. I've migrated it to our meta site. Please take a look at [this canonical resource list](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english) which I believe will come in handy.