# How can get help from this community if I can't hear some audio clearly?

Tags: discussion, questions, on-topic-off-topic

Recently I am learning the Cambridge practice tests for IELTS, the listening part is the most difficult for me. Even if I look at the transcripts when I am listening to the audio, I find that there are many linking sounds, weakness, and assimilation in spoken English; sometimes the sentences are simple but I can't hear clearly what the native speaker says.

I try to upload the mp3 audio in my Dropbox, and ask for help in English Language Learners. My posts often were closed, marked as

> Closed. This question is off-topic. It is not currently accepting answers.

This type of questions are not welcomed here!

If I want to get help from this community, what would be a good method to do so?

Comment: ELL is for answering specific types of questions, it doesn't exist to do everything you might have trouble with. Read [how to ask a good question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Doing audio transcriptions is not one of the site's primary purposes. If you need an audio recording transcribed, there are websites where you can pay for it; you could also ask teachers or members of your class for help, or find a discussion forum website for English learners.

Comment: Our [Resources for learning English](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/953/9161) post her on Meta has a "Exchanging online with a partner" section that might be helpful. If you can narrow your question down to a specific spoken pattern you're having trouble with, that sort of question might be on-topic. Here is an example of a well received question tagged with [tag:spoken-english] https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/217778/9161