# Are there conversation forums?

Tags: discussion, online-resources

I have two friends who are learning English and badly need to practice speaking. Are there any sites that help with that? They live in the UK but are surrounded by many nationalities, and having contact with more than one language when you have English as a target is very disruptive.

Even a mild direction towards where I could look for such sites or people would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [Exchanging online with a partner](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/953/41273)

Comment: Yes, definitely! Thanks!

Comment: There is the ELL chat room itself at https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24938/language-overflow which is available to anyone with over 20 rep on the ELL site.