# Can you suggest any AI based voice chat robot (such as some website) to practice spoken English?

Tags: discussion, resource-request, online-resources

I see these days, some text based on an AI robot, such as ChatGPT that can input English text, and respond in English, so I can practice my  English writing.

But I'm not an English native speaker, and I would like to practice my spoken English, so I would like to find some website or APP to have a conversation with the voice. A website is preferred, because I can use it in the browser in my phone and my PC.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there conversation forums?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/are-there-conversation-forums)

Comment: Hi, @MarcInManhattan thanks for the comment, I looked at the link you suggested, and I found that I don't find a voice chat program or website that I can practice my spoken English. The link mainly points to the question and answer here: [Resources for learning English](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english)

Comment: Then, because this question is asking essentially the same thing as that one (as far as I can tell), isn't that the answer? My understanding is that if you think that there might be other answers and want to draw attention to the issue to solicit new ones, the best thing is to edit the old question, which will bump it on the homepage, not create a new one. I hope someone will correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Doesn't look like a duplicate to me. The other question was asking about places to talk to other people while this question is asking for AI to talk to (which has its downsides but is probably less stressful for some people).

Comment: @Laurel Oh, I agree that a request for AI chat would be different. I didn't quite make that connection between the second and third paragraphs. OP: Can you please edit your question to make it a little clearer? I'd be happy to remove my close vote if that's the case.

Comment: Hi, @MarcInManhattan I think My question is quite simple, I would like to find some learning resource about "English voice based chat robot" which can have conversation with me. It would be a website or something similar(maybe APP), but the free service is preferred, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"ChatGPT but a voice chat robot" *is* ChatGPT, but that feature is still in the process of being rolled out.

See [ChatGPT can now see, hear, and speak](https://openai.com/blog/chatgpt-can-now-see-hear-and-speak) for more information:

> We’re rolling out voice and images in ChatGPT to Plus and Enterprise users over the next two weeks. Voice is coming on iOS and Android (opt-in in your settings) and images will be available on all platforms.
>
> [...]
>
> Speak with ChatGPT and have it talk back
> You can now use voice to engage in a back-and-forth conversation with your assistant. Speak with it on the go, request a bedtime story for your family, or settle a dinner table debate.
>
> To get started with voice, head to Settings → New Features on the mobile app and opt into voice conversations. Then, tap the headphone button located in the top-right corner of the home screen and choose your preferred voice out of five different voices.
>
> The new voice capability is powered by a new text-to-speech model, capable of generating human-like audio from just text and a few seconds of sample speech. We collaborated with professional voice actors to create each of the voices. We also use Whisper, our open-source speech recognition system, to transcribe your spoken words into text.