# Resources for learning the proper shape of the mouth and the position of the tongue in pronunciation

Tags: discussion, resource-request

Could you please recommend some learning materials (books, videos, websites, etc…) that those who are learning English as a second language can use to train native pronunciation of American English?

I would like to know about materials on the shape of the mouth and the position of the tongue in pronunciation.

There is no such thing in [this answer](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1057/177042) as far as I can tell from the description.

Comment: Are questions about the materials the scope of the meta?

Comment: Questions asking for resources are definitely within the scope of this Meta. Your question was closed for being a duplicate of another answered question. You have now added more detail to your request which may make it not a duplicate anymore. A mod closed this, and I've sent her a message. She may reopen it herself, but feel free to click the "Reopen" button in the meantime and let other users vote to reopen it.

Comment: This is a great example of how editing should work—reopened.